# Windows Firewall Programming

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, driver, firewall

I googled many times till I created this question, so please excuse me if there are some tutorials out there. I didn't found them.
How can I code a firewall application in windows? I thought about a usermode fiewall using inline hooks in every process, but there is the problem that I can't hook csrss.exe (which creates the new processes) in windows 7. The second thing is that it's not very clean and will be detected as malware for sure.
So I think that I should hook the APIs in kernel mode as a driver. But there are 3 problems.

- First I don't know the kernel APIs
  for the windows sockets.
- Second I havent't got any experience in kernel
  mode hooks.
- Third I don't know if
  it's the right way.

Don't worry, I know that it's not easy and I'm not a beginner with jsut an idea ;). If anyone has got good information please share it.
Oh and I want to write for x86 Systems ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WFP).

> With the WFP API, developers can
>   implement firewalls, intrusion
>   detection systems, antivirus programs,
>   network monitoring tools, and parental
>   controls. WFP integrates with and
>   provides support for firewall features
>   such as authenticated communication
>   and dynamic firewall configuration
>   based on applications' use of sockets
>   API (application-based policy). WFP
>   also provides infrastructure for IPsec
>   policy management, change
>   notifications, network diagnostics,
>   and stateful filtering.