# Windows: What would be involved with creating our own firewall for distribution with our product?

Tags: java, windows, firewall

I am charged with determining what would be involved with creating our own firewall.

Something that can intercept each and every connection, and decide whether to permit it based on which exe is initiating the connection. We would either block or hang the connection until the user said to permit or deny.

I am interested in XP, Vista, Win7.

I know how to program in Java, Perl and JavaScript. I am assuming that I am going to need to get Java to interface with some C or C# executable in order to make this work. I expect the GUI alerts will be Java based, but the big thing is knowing what interfaces with Windows would be needed, and if there is a major difference between XP and Vista/7.

I assume there are certain decisions to make, perhaps some compatibility issues. Please describe what would be involved.

I also posted [a related question for the possibility of simply tapping into the built in Windows Firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572875/built-in-windows-firewall-lock-outgoing-connections) because I want to hear about both options separately.

Comment: You are going to need to learn C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112835/windows-firewall-programming) To paraphrase the answer given in that post, you would need to make use of the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. As it's OS based, you would need to either write or find API wrappers that translate the C/C++ into something Java could call if you want to go that route.

If you need a network level firewall, you can start by looking at either [ipcop](http://ipcop.org/) or [Symantec Endpoint](http://www.symantec.com/business/endpoint-protection) for freebie and commercial solutions respectively. Endpoint does client side protection as well and other products exist such as [Avast](http://www.avast.com/en-us/index) or [ESET/NOD32](http://www.eset.com/us/home/products/smart-security) that offer firewall capabilities for free or at decent cost.

Unless it's an absolute necessity, I would advise looking into commercially available options before diving into writing your own.

Comment: The firewall we come up with will be distributed with our own program. An external device is not what I am talking about. Whatever we use needs to run on Windows because that is what the product is for. It looks like this could be accomplished with WFI API, but it seems that was only introduced in Vista. It is understandable if XP works differently, but we prefer something that works on all of them of course.

Comment: Your link to the other question was helpful. It pointed out that XP is going to be more difficult and also it pointed out what direction I would have to go to make this work. I am still holding out hope that we can [detect blocked outbound connection exe using the Windows Firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585045/windows-built-in-firewall-detect-a-blocked-outgoing-connection).

Answer (score 1):

Writing a driver in C, in other words, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that your only two options are to code one or use the one from Microsoft?

There are others, you know:  http://lifehacker.com/5061933/five-best-windows-firewalls

Comment: As long as the third party firewall can be distributed freely, and we can be in control of the GUIs (for example, configure it through the command line), a third option may be viable.

Comment: Ah - freely distributable.  I didn't see that in the question. Then you'll want an "open source firewall".  There are several.  I've only ever heard about one (smoothwall), but that's for gnu/linux.