# Built-In Windows Firewall: Lock outgoing connections?

Tags: windows, command-line, firewall, windows-firewall

By default, the Windows Firewall seems to block incoming (locally created listen sockets) connections by default. They can then be permitted per exe file.

Is it possible to configure something similar for outgoing connections? So Windows would ask whether to allow or deny an exe's outgoing connections.

We are considering creating a custom GUI to enable or disable this functionality, if available. It is a lower-cost option compared to [creating our own firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572852/windows-what-would-be-involved-with-creating-a-socket-level-firewall).

I would like to know about XP and Vista/Win7.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think ServerFault would be a better place for this because they would be more familiar with the command-line capabilities of the firewall.

Comment: this belongs on Stack Overflow -- there are software APIs to interface with Windows Firewall. And since "This is for distribution with a product of ours" it is not a sysadmin task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Windows are you asking about?  I'm sure that control of outgoing connections wasn't available when Windows first introduced a built-in firewall.  If you need to support WinXP RTM, I think you're s-o-l.

Many third-party firewalls do provide this capability.

Comment: I am interested in XP, and Vista and Win7.

Comment: Vista: I found where you set whether it blocks outbound, also found where you can tell it whether or not to ask to unblock, but it will not ask to unblock outbound. I posted [a followup question](http://serverfault.com/questions/316428/does-windows-firewall-have-the-ability-to-log-which-exe-is-blocked).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to block one specific EXE (that you have control of the source for)?  Or all programs on the computer from making outbound connections?  Why would you want to do this?  And if it's about admin policy control, why not control this on a central firewall?

In any case, take a look at the Windows Firewall APIs.  It lets you create all the crazy rules you want to block/allow traffic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I want a default block all policy, and I want to allow programs on a per exe basis. This is for distribution with a product of ours.